# UIButton with UIControlEventTouchDown, image won't change to selected until finger lifted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Trying to get my head around this. I have a UIButton with a UIControlEventTouchDown event that calls:

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"button pressed");

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.selected = YES;
}
```

I am getting the ,message "button pressed" instantly as expected. However the image won't change to the one of selected until I lift my finger. This doesn't make sense as I am setting the button to selected as soon as the button is pressed. I have my off image set in the interface builder for "default" and my on image set under "selected". I have tried also adding an image in for "highlighted" and this also doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [button setNeedsDisplay];?

Comment: Tried that...nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have setup your button clicked event on `UIControlEventTouchDown` so the event will fire on TouchDown event of the button and you want to set the image on that so you have to set image's `UIControlState`.

so try to set image like that :

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `highlighted` image for your button. In storyboard its like this: [image]

Comment: Maybe this doesnt work because you kind of hack the buttons state when setting it manually in your `UIControlEventTouchDown` event ? Try to remove the `button.selected = YES`

Comment: Yes! that's it! However I want to keep the image to "On" when I take my finger off. How do I do that?

Comment: I guess what I mean is how do I reverse the image each time?

Comment: Ok, I did this a couple of times but I dont remember exactly.... I think you could actually keep your code in your IBAction but instead of triggering this on `UIControlEventTouchDown` use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Comment: I need a touch down event though.

Comment: Ok, thats ok, you can keep it for other stuff. But dont change the state in `UIControlEventTouchDown`. try to do it in `UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"button pressed");
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
button.selected = YES;
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"another.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.